# Selenium 3.0.0 - Wrong item is selected in dropdownbox when using IE 11 browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

When I run the IE driver then it keeps selecting the wrong item in the dropdownbox. It looks like it is only happening at the items that are last in the drop down box.

for example I want to select item 9 in the dropdownbox but when I run the code below, it selects item 8. This only happens with IE driver.

When running this then it selected the wrong item.

```
Dropdownbox.get(9).click();
```

When I run this , then it select the correct Item

```
Dropdownbox.get(2).click();
```

---

My Environment: Selenium 3.0.0 and IE webdriver 3.0.0.0 AND
I'am also using POM (Page Object Model)

```
@FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME,using = "select2-result-label")
private List<WebElement> Dropdownbox;
```

Comment: Have you got the relevant HTML to go with this, that you can share?

Comment: I cannot share the HTML as the company is sensitive about sharing any company content

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation.
I had to identify 3 elements: The dropdownbox, allOptions in the dropdownbox and inputTextbox in the dropdownbox.

I created this method to solve the issue

```
public static void selectItemInDropdownBox(WebElement dropdownbox,WebElement inputSearch,List<WebElement> allOptionsList,String selectedItem){

         //Wait for dropdownbox to display on page
        browser.ExplicitWait(dropdownbox);
        //Now Click on dropdownbox to show the inputTextbox and allOptions
        dropdownbox.click();

        // Must now wait for allOptions to display
        browser.ExplicitWait(inputSearch);
        // Type now the searched Item
        inputSearch.sendKeys(selectedItem);

        //Now if the search item has more than 1 returned item then we need to select the correct one
        int counter = 0;
        for ( WebElement i: allOptionsList) { 
            if ( i.getText().trim().equals( selectedItem ) ) {
                allOptionsList.get(counter).click();
                break;
           }
            counter++; 
        }
    }
```

Here are my Explicit Waits : First one is for WebElement and second one is for a list

```
public static void ExplicitWait( WebElement WebElement){
        (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(WebElement));}

public static void ExplicitWaitList(List<WebElement> listWebElement){

    (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(listWebElement));
}
```